# How do I omit the caption of a continued table on the second page using tabularray

Tags: captions, tabularray

In my MWE I can omit the caption of the table when it starts. but as soon as it breaks over to the next page I get the caption.

I want to have no caption at all.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[%
  label=none,
  entry=none,
  long
  ]{rowhead=1,
    colspec={X}}
  My text\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}` and `\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}` to hide caption and foot.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}
\begin{tblr}[%
  label=none,
  entry=none,
  long
  ]{rowhead=1,
    colspec={X}}
  My text\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
  \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to a preamble

```
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}    % Removes a caption
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}    % Removes a caption on subsequent pages
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}   % Removes text denoting continuation on next page
```