# how can I remove "Continued on next page 3" from my table

Tags: tables

how can i remove this?
[image]

```
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Mengen, Parameter und Entscheidungsvariablen des \\ Optimierungsmodells},
      label = {Tabelle 3.1}
                    ]{colspec={@{} Q[l, mode=math] X[j] @{}},
                     rowhead=1
                     }     
    \toprule
    Notation    & Beschreibung/Definition       \\
        \midrule
    \SetCell[c=2]{c, mode=text}    Mengen              
                &                               \\
        \midrule
    A   & die Menge der Kanten                  \\
    V   & die Menge der Knoten                \\
    P   & Menge der Abholungsknoten, $P:=\lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$           \\
    D   & Menge der Auslieferungsknoten, $D:=\lbrace n+1,...,n+m \rbrace$   \\
    K   & Menge der Fahrzeuge                   \\
        \midrule
    \SetCell[c=2]{c, mode=text}    Parameter          
        &                                       \\
        \midrule
    n   & die Anzahl der Abholungsknoten        \\
    m   & die Anzahl der Auslieferungsknoten    \\
    q_i & Angebot/Nachfrage in Knote i; die Abholungsknoten haben positivem
          Wert, die Auslieferungsknoten haben negativem Wert; 
          im Beginn des Depots und am Ende des Depots sind die 
          Angebote/Nachfrage gleich 0, $q_0 = q_{n+m+1} = 0$. Jeder Abholungsknoten ist mit einem bestimmten Auslieferungsknoten verbunden, $q_i = -q_{n+i}$    \\
    z_i & die Reihenfolge-Nummer bei dem Besuch in einer Tour   \\
    d_i & die Bedienungsdauer am Knoten i   \\
    t^k_{ij} & die Reisezeit von i nach j mit dem Fahrzeug $k$    \\
    c^k_{ij} & die Distanz der Kante $(i, j)$ mit dem Fahrzeug $k$  \\
    C^k & die Kapazit\"at des Fahrzeugs $k$     \\
    M & eine ausreichende gro\ss{}e Zahl\\
        \midrule
    \SetCell[c=2]{c, mode=text} Entscheidungsvariablen           
        &                                       \\
        \midrule
    x^{k}_{ij} 
    & $= 1$ falls Kanten $(i, j)$ mit Fahrzeug $k$ zur kostenminimaler 
          Rundreis geh\"ort (0 sonst)           \\
    Q^k_i & die Beladung des Fahrzeugs $k$ beim Verlassen des Knoten $i$    \\
    B^k_i & der Beginn der Bedienung des Fahrzeugs k am Knoten $i$    \\
        % \midrule[dashed]
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
```

Comment: Hi, What is the minimal working example starting from documentclass? Please not put a snippet code.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs} `
do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pag. 40 of the [tabularray](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) package there is written the possibility to remove "Continued on next page 3" from your table. See the command `\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}`.

[image]

Comment: `\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}` it worked but name of the head can't remove

Comment: `\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}`
i solved it. It also need this one

Comment: @Renxian Possible related here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659105/how-do-i-omit-the-caption-of-a-continued-table-on-the-second-page-using-tabularr