# How to get notes in tabularray / tblr?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularray, threeparttable, tablenotes

I've tried getting notes inside of the `tbrl` environment, but it just adds the superscripted letters inside of the table. It doesn't add the actual contents of the notes below the table.

[image: tblr environment not printing note contents]

Now this can be fixed with a `talltblr` environment but it forces another caption upon the table which I do not want, as I am using `caption` to make my figures and tables bold.

[image: talltblr environment adding a second caption, but printing note contents]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption}

    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
    \captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Pipettierschema Teilversuch 1 (Angaben in \textmu l)}
\label{tab:ps1}
\begin{tblr}[note{a} = {Test},
 note{b} = {Test 2},
 remark{Note} = {Notes, test test test},
 remark{Source} = {Sources, test test test test test},
]{colspec = {
                        %@{}
                            c X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                              X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                         *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                        X[c, si={table-format=1.0}]
                        @{}
                        },
             row{1}  = {guard, m, cmd=\hskip0pt} 
            }
\toprule
{nº} & {Bidestilliertes Wasser \TblrNote{a}} & {Imidazol-\\puffer \TblrNote{b}} & {NADH} & {Pyruvat} & {Lactat}\\ 
\midrule
  1 & 923 & 50 & 20 & 5 & 2 \\
  2 & 913 & 50 & 20 & 15 & 2 \\ 
  3 & 903 & 50 & 20 & 25 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Additionally, how would I go about changing the "*Note*" and "*Source*" part of the notes to the German equivalents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`talltblr` uses the syntax of `longtblr`. So you should use options `caption` and `label` for the caption and the label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption}

    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
    \captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Pipettierschema Teilversuch 1 (Angaben in \textmu l)},
  label = {tab:ps1},
  note{a} = {Test},
  note{b} = {Test 2},
  remark{Hinweis} = {Notes, test test test},
  remark{Quelle} = {Sources, test test test test test},
]{colspec = {
                        %@{}
                            c X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                              X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                         *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                        X[c, si={table-format=1.0}]
                        @{}
                        },
             row{1}  = {guard, m, cmd=\hskip0pt} 
            }
\toprule
{nº} & {Bidestilliertes Wasser \TblrNote{a}} & {Imidazol-\\puffer \TblrNote{b}} & {NADH} & {Pyruvat} & {Lactat}\\ 
\midrule
  1 & 923 & 50 & 20 & 5 & 2 \\
  2 & 913 & 50 & 20 & 15 & 2 \\ 
  3 & 903 & 50 & 20 & 25 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The captions of `tabularray` environments `longtblr` and `talltblr` are setup using templates and styles. So to have a bold tag for the caption, you can use:

```
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
```

or short:

```
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{\bfseries}
```

to get:

[image: now with bold tag]

See the `tabularray` manual for more information.

Comment: Is there any way to get them `para` and `flushleft` like in `threeparttable` ?

Comment: @m0n74g3 The notes are also controlled by templates. See section 4.2.4 of the manual or ask a new question.

Comment: Is there no way to use notes of a tblr without specifying a caption/label? I want do the latter in my normal `table*` environment.

Comment: @ChristophThiede This would be another question, which IMHO [already has been answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/659105/277964). If not, please ask a new question with suitable minimal working example.